# Use c:set in FreeMarker

Tags: jsp, freemarker

I would need to migrate the following sentence from JSP to FreeMarker:

```
<c:set var="myVariable" scope="session" value="myValue"/>
```

The key point here is that the JSP sentence is storing the variable in the current Session, so the variable is available for the following requests.

I have tried using the JspTaglibs wrapper as follows:

```
<#assign c=JspTaglibs["http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"]>
```

But I get an error cause the *JspFactory.getDefaultFactory()* in use is the standard one (I am within a J2EE container, aka WLS):

> ```
>  Can not create an ELContext using a foreign JspApplicationContext
>  Consider dropping a private instance of JSP 2.1 API JAR file in
>  your WEB-INF/lib directory and then try again.
> ```

I don't know if/how I can force to use the FreeMarker JspFactory implementation, or if there is another way to store things session from FreeMarker.

Comment: Why does an MVC View write the session? I understand that you are just migrating, but if you address this suspected design issue, you avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: Also, do you only need the JSP support for `c:set`? If so, then you could write a `TemplateDirectiveModel` that does what you want, instead of fighting with the JSP support. Or if you need JSP support anyway, then your problem is not session writing at the moment, but that JSP support doesn't work altogether.